# Find the position of an element within a list

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to find the position (i.e. the order) of a clicked element within a list using jQuery.

I have:

```
<ul>
 <li>Element 1</li>
 <li>Element 2</li>
 <li>Element 3</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

On click of an `<li>`, I want to store it's position within a variable. For example, if I clicked on Element 3, then "3" would be stored in a variable.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient version of Cletus' answer, which doesn't require finding parents and children:

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Element 1</li>
 <li>Element 2</li>
 <li>Element 3</li>
 <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 35):

Use [`index()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index):

```
$("li").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
  alert("You clicked item " + index);
});
```

Indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with plain **JavaScript**:

```
let = _this = this,
      indx = Array.prototype.slice.call(_this.parentElement.childNodes).indexOf(_this);
```

Or, if you trying to style your ordered html list with other than CSS like `<hr>`, as @Jan mentioned, use `querySelectorAll('li')` instead of `childNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer works fine. 2 additions:
When your list contains listitems of `<a>` for example:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li><a href="#">Element 1</a></li>
  <hr /><hr />
  <li><a href="#">Element 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Element 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

then you have to use `var index = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this);`

Also like in above example the list contains other elements like `<hr />` than you can use a filter in `var index = $(this).parent().parent().children("li").index(this);` to give you index 2 for "element 3" instead of index 4.

Comment: Good answer, I would expand it saying that `$(this).closest('ul').children('li').index(this);` is event a better solution.

Comment: Can't think of a situation when developer would use `<hr>` inside html ordered list, except the border decoration, and for this purpose Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) will be more practical, on my opinion, unless developer like to be different.