# How to get index of <li> element

Tags: jquery

I was looking into post 
[Find the position of an element within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046307/find-the-position-of-an-element-within-a-list),
and Mr cletus mentioned that to get index we have to use

```
var index = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
```

HTML:

```
               <ul>
               <li>Element 1</li>
               <li>Element 2</li>
               <li>Element 3</li>
               </ul>
```

My question is why `$(this).index(this)` does not work(it always renders 0), whereas `$(this).html()` renders proper html output. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `$(this)` references to the `<li>` element, and by using `$(this).index(this)`, you are essentially asking the index of the current element inside itself - which obviously is 0.

Comment: oh..ok..got ur point...yes its asking the index of the current element inside itself.  Thanks