# Getting index of clicked list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the index of the clicked element in a list?

So if I have the following list:

- First
- Second
- Third

When I click `Third`, I would like to get the index `2`, provided the index starts with `0`.

With my code I only get `0`s:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="listElem">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="listElem">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="listElem">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".listElem").click(function(param) {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3v5fyxf/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get index of <li> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048718/how-to-get-index-of-li-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `parent()` to return index of `li` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/y3v5fyxf/1/)

```
$(".listElem").click(function(param) {
  console.log($(this).parent().index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".listElem").click(function(param) {
  console.log($(".listElem").index(this));
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y3v5fyxf/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("li").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
  alert("You clicked item " + index);
});
```